# How to offset the RefreshControl

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm using the [`RefreshControl`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html) component in a list that scroll underneath a semi-transparent app-header-bar.

My only problem is that the RefreshControl appears underneath the semi-transparent header. What I really want is to be able to offset the y position of the RefreshControl so that it reveals directly below the app-header-bar.

I've tried using various style properties (`marginTop`, `paddingTop`, `translateY`), but nothing seems to do the job.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

According to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6740) in IOS,

> If you set a contentInset top to a scrollview, RefreshControl starts from that point.

In android you can use parameter 'progressViewOffset' to a value to achieve the same.

```
 <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
        onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
        progressViewOffset={offset}
      />
```

This feature will be released in react-native version [0.27](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.27.0-rc). [Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f7ce0c1c2fd2d6dacbf2c76cf43f48d245e8779d) is the commit which added support in android.

Answer (score 1):

If any one is having this issue in 2022, `progressViewOffset` seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @Sohail Khan.

Comment: No magic happening boss. The prop was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37437668/5141143) and according to the docs, works for both iOS and Android now. Essentially does how it's named, adds a vertical offset to the progress component.